# ID generator: class variable vs while yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have some class which gives each instance a unique ID on creation. I can do this in one of 2 ways but do not know which is better practice. The first way is to use a class variable and classmethod to set the ID. A user could mess with this by calling something like `SomeClass.unique_id = something` but this is very unlikely. The second way is to use a staticmethod with a yield and an infinite while loop. I have shown both methods below (note that both methods only have the same name for example purposes).

```py
class SomeClass():
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = self.generate_id()

    # Method 1:
    unique_id = 0
    @classmethod
    def generate_id(cls):
        cls.unique_id += 1
        return cls.unique_id

    # Method 2:
    @staticmethod
    def generate_id():
        unique_id = 0
        while True:
            unique_id += 1
            yield unique_id
```

Which method is better practice to use in my code?

Comment: How would you use the second method? (Since you've only shown how you'd use the first one)

Comment: @superbrain exactly the same way. There is no difference in the output of the 2 methods nor the way they are called from within the class

Comment: That's not true. If you use the first method like that, your `self.id` is a number. If you use the second method like that, `self.id` is a generator. So you'd at least need to use `next` on it. But since different `SomeClass` instances get different generators, each would get the id `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using `itertools.count()`, which works basically like your generator function:

```py
import itertools 
class SomeClass:
    id_counter = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self.id_counter)


a, b = SomeClass(), SomeClass()
print(a.id)  # output: 0
print(b.id)  # output: 1
```

The issue with the user messing your unique id value by writing something like `a.id = 'banana'` is another issue, and more or less inherent to Python's flexibility, although you can't really stop them from doing so. If I write `np.array = list`, that's on me.